# Delegate in Rails breaks migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Parent` class, which delegates some methods to `Son`. In my migrations, I create `Parent` first, then `Son` later.

Now, if I drop database and recreate it, at the time `parents` table is created, `sons` table has not been created. My code breaks because at this moment, because the `Parent` delegates method to `Son`, who has not been created.

I have tried to avoid this migration trouble by creating a condition:

```
if defined? Son == 'constant' && Son.class == Class
  #do delegation here
end
```

However, this will break my code in other situations. For example, when I run the app, and has not initialized `Son`, the test `define? Son == 'constant'` will fale.

How should I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 0):

This code should move to initializers and removed from migration. Since, migration has nothing to do with it. This will make your migrations clean.